# How can you load a page fragment with jQuery in Laravel 4?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I like to load a page fragment using jQuery like this:

```
$(".title" + nid ).click(function() {

   $('.loadNest').load("{{ View::make('postDetails') }}");

});
```

Is this possible? I have a list of post titles on the left of my page. When a user clicks on a post title I want to load a page fragment on the right with all the details of the post. The author, the comments, etc...all on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `load` method is actually an AJAX call, so you'd have to set up a route that would output the view. Something like this:

```
Route::get('ajax/postDetails', array(
    'as' => 'postDetailsView', // This is the name of your route
    'do' => function () {
        return View::make('postDetails');
    }
));
```

Then, in your code, you'd have:

```
$('.title' + nid).click(function() { // Use the route's name you setup
    $('.loadNest').load('{{ URL::route('postDetailsView') }}');
});
```

Comment: Not able to get it to work. Were you able to test it successfully on your end?

Comment: I have not seen the 'do' used in this context before. Is there a specific reason to use it here like this?

Comment: `do` is for `Closures` what `uses` is for controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using this jQuery code:

```
$(".nestTitle").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url: "getNest",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(fragment) { 
      $(".loadNest").html(fragment);
    });
});
```

Which called my route like this:

```
Route::get('getNest', array('as' => 'getNest', 'uses' => 'NestsController@getNest'));
```

Then in my controller I did this:

```
    $nid = 105;
    $uid = Auth::user()->id;
    $nests = Nest::with('user')
    ->where('user_id', '=', $uid)
    ->where("id", $nid)
    ->get();

    return View::make('nestItems', compact('nests'));
```

I just need to pass the parameters around and I should be good. Thanks for your help Raphael.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution that I use is to use asset in your javascript

```
$(".title" + nid ).click(function() {

   $('.loadNest').load("{{ asset('postDetails') }}");

});
```

and setup the Route as

```
Route::get('/postDetails', function() {
    return View::make('postDetails');
});
```